# Make Xbox One controller work without new kernel

Tags: steam, gamepad

I need to get my Xbox One controller to work with my computer, specifically to play games on Dolphin and Steam. I don't  want to upgrade my kernel to the one with Xbox One support, in fear that it'll break my Nvidia driver. Are there any other options to get the controller working?

Comment: Other than building your own kernel, no there's no way to 'get the controller to work'

Comment: Does the earliest kernel with support for Xbox One controllers also support Nvidia drivers?

Comment: In new kernel would not be better support for NVIDIA driver? (I hope so) Or go to the X.Org driver then upgrade kernel than try nVidia driver. Or stay on X.Org driver after you upgraded kernel and install NVIDIA X Server Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Build your own kernel, starting with your current version. Then step through each source change between that version and the version with Xbox support. Apply it or not, depending on your decision as to the change's contribution to "Xbox support" or "breaks Nvidia". Be sure to test frequently.

This is probably more work than you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The XboxOne driver is in `drivers/input/joystick/xpad.c`, you should be able to copy that out of a newer kernel into an older kernel and compile or compile the module on it's own.